# Falied to to create a bootable USB stick

Tags: 13.10, usb, windows-7, startup-disk-creator

When I tried to create a bootable USB stick using Startup Disk Creator in my Ubuntu 13.10

My source is a Windows 7

After 77% of conclusion appear this message in a file below

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what Windows7 has to do with it. But I'd really like to know what that taskbar is called. Very pretty. :) Try to add more details and it'll be easier to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the PC dual boot?

OR, is **Ubuntu 13.10** (or Windows 7) in a virtual container?

---

### ***Wild guess::***

The last stages of creating a 'LiveUSB' needs a compatible kernel and boot files (from somewhere) and *Startup Disk Creator* writes these to the USB in *privileged mode*.

This is NOT the *just* the standard **13.10** install, so anything could be wrong here ..

Comment: I can see a "WinXP Executando" button at the bottom, so there is a VM running. So your guess is probably correct: WinXP tries to write to the USB in privileged mode.

Comment: Or **13.10** tries to write to USB (in privileged mode) from inside a VM. *Needs more details ..*